# Django modelform submission with relational data

Tags: python, django

I have a django modelform that creates a new `listing` in my `post` app, I would like to associate this with a `company` id, which is an account type in my `account` app.

The `account_company` db table (postgresql) has a `user_id` field which is the `pk` of `User`. the `post_listing` table will have a `company` field which I think should be the `pk` of `account_company`.

As I am attempting to use modelforms for all forms, I am having an issue with making this association.

```
# models.py

class Listing(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   ...
```

```
# forms.py

class newListingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        fields = ('title'...)

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(newListingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['company'].queryset = Company.objects.filter(pk__user_id=user.id) 
    # above i am trying to filter the AutoField to the `company pk` where `user_id` is equal to `request.user.id`
```

```
# views.py

def post(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = newListingForm(request.user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            listing = form.save(commit=False)
            listing.user = request.user
            listing.save()
    else:
        form = newListingForm(request.user)
    return render(request, 'post/post.html', {'form': form})
```

The debug error i get is:

`Unsupported lookup 'user_id' for AutoField or join on the field not permitted.`

**Updated**

```
#accounts model.py

...
class Company(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d/', null=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
```

Comment: change `Company.objects.filter(pk__user_id=user.id)` to `Company.objects.filter(user_id=user.id) ` is still throws same error?

Comment: Can you also include your `Company` model for completeness?

Comment: @shotgunner with that change it gives just `company` as an error, however the company field is defined in the model..

Comment: @Mekicha added the accounts model.py with the `Company` model, here the `OneToOneField` says `user`, however in the db it is stored as `user_id`

Comment: What does " it gives just company as an error" mean? Show the full new error.

Comment: `Company.objects.filter(user=user)` should fix your problem

Comment: @Navid2zp it does not, returns the same error as my comment above

Comment: @DanielRoseman it literally just says company as a key error where it was saying Unsupported lookup before, for my experience level it isn't very helpful as far as error reporting goes

Comment: But *show that error*. Also show the bits of the form you've snipped. Is `company`actually in the fields list?

Comment: @DanielRoseman no it was not, after putting it in i was getting a `__str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)` error, but by removing the `def __str__(self):
        return self.name` from the Company model it loads the page, have not yet tried submitting to see if it works properly. Any insight on this? Is this because it is null? Can `__str__` not be null?

Comment: Oh awesome, that did work. So the issue was that it wasn't correctly in the field list, and that my filter was wrong. For clarification, `name.objects.filter` returns the `pk` of the results by default, is that why we are omitting `pk__`?